# Google Analytics - how to track across domains when we use Universal Analytics and other domain uses Traditional?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We're trying to track users across domains from our site to another domain (payment processor).  We are using Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`) but the other site is using Traditional (`ga.js`).  In fact they are using both, but they are using ga.js to register our GA ID and universal to track their GA ID.

If both parties were using Universal Analytics then it could be accomplished by appending a `_ga=$_gaCookieValue` url parameter to all links pointing from our site to theirs.  Since they are using `ga.js` for our GA Id this url parameter is not getting picked up and registered on their site.

Does anyone know how we might solve this mismatch?  We're pressing the other site for help but have come up short so far.

Comment: Does the payment gateway direct back to your page ? Then you could add their domain to your referral exclusions, and at least have correct campaign attribution. Else see Philip Waltons answer.

Comment: It does and we've begun doing that (excluding their domains).  I guess that about as much as we can hope for short of getting them to upgrade the tracking of our GA id via `analytics.js` instead of `ga.js`.  Thanks for the confirmation that the referral exclusion list should sort out campaign tracking for us, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ga.js` does not support this type of communication with `analytics.js`, so what you're asking to do is just not possible without a lot of hacking or manual implementation on their part, which would be a total waste of time since it'll be **much** easier for them to just upgrade their implementation to `analytics.js` and then use the officially supported [Linker plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) to get out of-the-box, cross-domain tracking.